# How do I check that RVM + Bundler are working correctly (and that I can avoid "bundle exec")? I'm slightly confused over wording in the docs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rvm, bundler, configuration-files

I'm following this [Rails tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#sec-advanced_setup) section and [this RVM doc page](https://rvm.io/integration/bundler/) . My installation is all brand new (`RVM 1.17.3`), so, if I understand the tutorial and the RVM docs correctly:

- RVM and Bundler should be integrated by default and I don't have to configure anything. (No need to run `bundle --bunstubs`?)
- I don't need to type "bundle exec"

Did I read that right?

I don't see a `bundler_stubs/` or `bin/` directory in my application.

Is there a way for me to check that it's set up properly so I can be sure that `bundle exec` is not necessary?

---

**edit:**

Running `which` yields the following:

```
$ bundle show rspec    
$ /home/{username}/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@tutorial/gems/rspec-2.11.0
$ which rspec
$ /home/{username}/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@tutorial/bin/rspec
```

Which seems to imply that I should keep using `bundle exec` because they are not the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RVM by default installs gem https://github.com/mpapis/rubygems-bundler which detects if you are in context of `Gemfile` and automatically loads bundler if required, it is equivalent to manually typing `bundle exec`.

Answer (score 1):

**bundle exec** is a bundle command to execute a script in the context of the current bundle (the one from your directory's Gemfile). **rspec filename.rb** is the script.

so bundle exec  **bundle exec rspec filename.rb** executes the rake script with the command **rspec filename.rb** in the context of the current bundle.

As to the "why?" I'll quote from the bundler documentation:

**In some cases, running executables without bundle exec may work,
if the executable happens to be installed in your system and does not pull in any gems that conflict with your bundle. However, this is unreliable and is the source of considerable pain. Even if it looks like it works, it may not work in the future or on another machine.**

See http://gembundler.com/man/bundle-exec.1.html for more info.

Comment: The tutorial, and [this page](https://rvm.io/integration/bundler/) in the RVM docs however seem to imply that bundle exec is no longer necessary with RVM (as of RVM 1.11). -- This is what's confusing me. "Starting with 1.11.0 new RVM installations has it enabled by default."

Comment: Did you check this link https://github.com/mpapis/rubygems-bundler it gives more information rubygems-bundler && Noexec once check it.

Comment: Would simply generating a unique rvm gemset and running `bundle install` on every project not solve the problem? -- I don't understand why `bundle exec` is necessary if I'm already working under a project-specific gemset.

Comment: Check gem list in your terminal and check bundler versions.just tell me how many bundler versions are in gemset.

Comment: Just the one, but I just started Ruby yesterday so I've only one gemset.

Comment: Not only bundler and also rake, rspec ..etc .bundler dont know which version use the current application so based on that we use bunlde exec then it will take current applicatoin bundler versions. Suppose you have all gems having one version no need to run bundle exec otherwise may to use bundle exec.

Comment: the bigest problem is rake and bundler, they are by default instaled in rvm rubies global gemsets, this leads to using higher version from global when lower is available in current gemset. This behavior of rubygems is different from python where the order of search path is respected for loading.